# Using a generator with Django's Paginator

Tags: python, django, pagination, generator, paginator

Is it possible for Django's Paginator to work with a Python generator?

For example, assuming I have a generator which will automatically paginate requests to an API like this pseudocode:

```
def get_response():
    page_one = requests.get('http://example.com/json?page=1')
    for item in page_one:
        yield item

    page_two = requests.get('http://example.com/json?page=2')
    for item in page_two:
        yield item
```

Could Django's Paginator be extended to support this generator?

```
generator = get_response()
paginator = Paginator(generator, 10)
```

I know this approach will work:

```
paginator = Paginator(list(generator), 10)
```

My understanding is that passing a generator directly would be more efficient because the API client would not make a request until it was required to do so. Though I understand that a Paginator requires a `count()` or `__len__()` method which may make this impossible.

Comment: Alex, you need to update your profile...

Comment: In addition to the length check, the paginator uses slice notation to get each page. I think you'd end up reimplementing a large portion of the paginator to change the assumptions that it works on something that can reasonably efficiently handle both of those.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this, but it would be of limited use.

The part of the Paginator class that slices the list to create a page is at [the end of the `page` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/407c1249c9a0296ec8a8d95e447bd695ca471b5e/django/core/paginator.py#L70). It does this via slicing of the object list; but obviously, a generator does not support slicing.

So the only thing you could do would be to replace that whole method, and instead of the slicing you would have to repeatedly call `next` on the generator until you got to the page you wanted. You would gain over calling `list()` on the whole object list, but the amount of code you'd need to replace probably wouldn't make it worthwhile to use this class at all.